# Android Calendar for Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am looking for a calendar to be displayed on the screen.. As per my knowledge the CalenderView widget is available from API level 11 .. 
Can the CalendarView be made compatible for API 10(Android 2.3.3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless they put it in the next version of the support libs, the answer is no.  You will need another calendar widget like this

http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/

Instructions : http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/wiki/HowToUse